Firebase Data Connect - insert many
I'm evaluating Firebase Data Connect and I'm stuck at a very basic task when using the insertMany functionality.
I would like to create a mutation that assigns permissions to a new role in the system. Let's imagine the following GQL schema:
    # Permission
    type Permission
      @table(
        name: "Permission"
        singular: "permission"
        plural: "permissions"
        key: ["id"]
      ) {
      id: UUID! @col(name: "permission_id") @default(expr: "uuidV4()")
      name: String! @unique
      type: String!
      description: String!
    }

    # Role
    type Role @table(name: "Role", singular: "role", plural: "roles", key: ["id"]) {
      id: UUID! @col(name: "role_id") @default(expr: "uuidV4()")
      name: String! @unique
      description: String!
    }

    # Role and Permission many-to-many relationship
    type RolePermission
      @table(
        key: ["role", "permission"] # join key for many-to-many
      ) {
      role: Role! @ref
      permission: Permission! @ref
    }

Data connect has the ability to do an insertMany operation, but... I have no clue how to write a mutation that does this. I tried the following:
    mutation assignPermissionsToRole($rolePermissions: [RolePermission_Data!]!) {
      rolePermission_insertMany(data: $rolePermissions)
    }

but it throws the following error:
mutation, assignPermissionsToRole On $rolePermissions: cannot use RolePermission_Data as a variable (please use one variable for each field instead, ex: {foo: $foo})
Does anyone have a clue how to use the insertMany option?

Honestly.. i find this is pretty annoying too. And thats not the only one where its restricted.. i cant even use @auth directives with tokens.
But.. if you do it from your cloud functions, and basically generate your query as a string, instead of passing that array as a variable.. it works.
ugly workaround :/

So it's not only me. Doing it by CF is a workaround, but.... I thought that the whole point of Data Connect was to automatically build the API and not have to deal with Cloud Functions doing what Data Connect should do in the first place.

i really hope this will be addressed .. once public preview is over.

this is a really annoying one.

@artanis99 Do you have any examples of mutating data connect from cloud functions? I can't seem to get it to work
